# How in a purely physical universe would a perfect recreation of a human not necessarily imply a "transfer" of its conciousness?

Tags: consciousness, materialism, physicalism

I've been kicking around this idea for a while and I have attempted to propose it in different forums yet the idea is treated as illogical but I cannot find/understand why it would be so impossible.

The idea goes as follows:

1. "Any object that exists (X) can be fully encapsulated by a set of physical attributes ({Q})
2. "Any property of a physical object (That is not quantum) can be measured and recreated"
3. "For consciousness to not be infinitely fragile it must not be a quantum property"
4. "If your particular subjective experience (not just subjective experience as a whole) is a physical property then it can be recreated"
5. "Information cannot be destroyed in a closed system"
6. "Any past object can be interpolated from the present state of a closed system"
7. "Your brain is an object and as such it could be reconstructed by future generations"

From the following step of points it follows that a likely thing to happen after death is immediately waking up in the far future as a future generation creates a replica of you, the only ways that I can come up for this not being the case are the following:

1. At no point in the lifetime of the universe does a civilization (with knowledge of humanity and life on earth) have the technology to clone an arbitrary object.
2. Despite the ungodly amounts of information both physical and digital that we archive and preserve, this information is not enough for any super-futuristic computer to interpolate a sufficiently precise to interpolate the emergent experience of any person living in the present.
3. Despite being able to do so, no future scientists for the whole of the universe's lifetime ever bother to recreate present day humans (neither for the scientific preservation or for ethical reasons)
4. Consciousness is a property emergent from an exact subatomic state at a quantum level however if this is the case then either

   4.1. Given that subatomic state changes practically instant and as far as we know       random any instant your conciousness dies and another one is formed

   4.2 There exists a hidden quantum variable that although immeasurable is turning complete

Although all are granted possible (particularly point 2) I do not that this points sufficiently disqualify this theory as something completely irrational, and I when proposing this idea Ive been have people tell me that even if the universe was purely physical and a perfect physical reconstruction of a person was made that would not suffice for the persons consciousness to "transfer over" as it where. Am I missing something? Why is this idea so irrational?
Anyway thanks.

Comment: The idea is not "completely irrational", it is even played on in TV shows like Feed or Upload. But why would it be "transfer" instead of just a replica of "consciousness" attached to the new body? Also, chances are that "consciousness" supervenes on dynamic processes, so a static copy of the brain ("as an object") at some point in time will not reproduce the "stream of consciousness" that, I am guessing, the "transfer" is getting at. The "ungodly amounts of information" that we know how to archive are static, and not even time slices of individual brains but rather some averaged surrogates.

Comment: There's nothing closed about the solar system. The whole thing is constantly pumping ~4x10^26 W of information-carrying photons out into deep space, never to be seen or heard from again.

Comment: If your so called consciousness is simplified to be only the totality of one's consistent histories as memories, then according to Leibniz's famous principle of identity of indiscernible (PII) under his spacetime relationalism, if there're 2 near clone copies of the history of same memories then they must be identical and identified even you see apparently 2 different persons! (why this is possible?) However, in reality their embodiment would be very different, so even with same memories to begin with, due to embodied cognition their meaning and consequence would be different going forward...

Comment: I’d recommend Derek Parfit’s work on persons, identity, and what matters for survival

Answer (score 1):

I think the weak point in your argument is your use of the word 'transfer'. If our conscious minds are the result of the configuration of the stuff in our brains, then if you could clone a brain with the exact same configuration you would expect it to have the same conscious experience. However, you would not have 'transferred' the consciousness but replicated it. Bear in mind that the original subject brain you copied could still be working away as normal, so you would have two brains, each with the same consciousness and sense of self. There is a nice thought experiment, in which the Star Trek transporter malfunctions to create five identical copies of Captain Kirk, and asks which is the 'real' Kirk?

Comment: Wouldn't it not transferring mean that they are not identical? as if what we consider your original "you" i.e what we consider as dying at the moment of your death exists in the original but not in the copy despite it having all of the same properties wouldn't it imply that there would have to be quality that is not included in the set of all physical properties (a metaphysical propriety)? I have no idea how it would work or "feel" but given the axioms of materialism wouldn't it follow that all Kirk's are equally real and as such equally contain the property of the original's consciousness?

Comment: @Decod621 I reached the conclusion that they were all real Kirks, since if they were identical (literally) then there would be no way to tell them apart, and each would think he was indeed the (italics implied) Kirk.

Answer (score 0):

When you wake up in the morning, you are aware that it's after "you" have gone to bed.

But there is not a continuous consciousness. The only thing that allows you to be aware of your previous consciousness is your memories.

If you were exactly cloned, so that 2 people wake up with your memories, both of them would believe themselves to be "you".

You could argue that they're both correct, or that "you" stop existing when you go to sleep at night when you lose consciousness, or that "you" only exist for an instant, to be replaced by another slightly different consciousness, or that "you" is the one who possesses your particular and specific set of atoms (although that last one might get you to the [ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) thought experiment). I don't have much of an opinion about that: it's semantics.

In any case, I would not say there's a "transfer" of consciousness, because that suggests some sort of transcendent consciousness that can be transferred, and it also suggests that one consciousness is unique (which is at odds with pure physicalism as well as with the idea of exactly recreating someone).

It is merely the case that if you were recreated at some point in the future, that person would believe themselves to be you. That is all. The conflict comes in when you appeal to some unique idea of "you", as opposed to "you" merely being an emergent property of your brain.

---

On an unrelated note, reflecting on the above might help alleviate a fear of death for some: the "you" that wakes up every morning could functionally just be a clone, so death shouldn't be much scarier than going to bed at night.